# Slow seeding/caching from GeoServer WMS to MapPRoxy

Tags: python, geoserver, wms, cache, mapproxy

I face a unormal speed of re-seeding (updating old tiles by new from one source - WMS GeoServer (in GeoServer this data taken from PostgreSQL source)) from 5.32% to this

```
[08:39:10] 11   5.42% -10175297.20532, 13149614.84996, -10018754.17139, 13306157.88388 (27568 tiles)
```

reseeding works for about 8 hours! 
We use CentOS, 16 gb RAM , SSD.
When seeding was running console throws this information:

> Limited to coverage in: -180.00000, -85.05113, 180.00000, 85.05113 (EPSG:4326)

It is ok? all my data in 3857... 
What be the reason of so slowly working (reseeding)? I don't want to update GeoServer to 2.16.0)

Comment: Was initial seeding faster?

Comment: @user30184 Yes! A first seeding was a more faster. World coverage with different difficulty of   style From 0 to 12 zoom level was cached by about 30 hours.

Comment: The comment doesn't seem to be related to seeding issues, simply factual. EPSG::3857 is limited to +/- 85 degrees latitude, whilst EPSG::4326 is global coverage

Comment: did you do any optimisation of your data? indexes on the attributes used in the style?